# MongoDB 3.6 fresh install

Tags: mongodb, upgrade, mongodb-3.6

I'm using mongodb 3.6.18
I'm running a cluster of 2 shards and 1 config replicaset.

I get this error when trying to set the compatibility version to 3.6:

```
global:PRIMARY> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "expected entry { _id: \"son.service_state\", lastmodEpoch: ObjectId('5f743676f790314e2a02cfd3'), lastmod: new Date(4294967296), dropped: false, key: { data_center: 1 }, unique: false } in config.collections for son.service_state to have a UUID, but it did not",
    "code" : 1,
    "codeName" : "InternalError",
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1601465931, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001")
    },
    "$configServerState" : {
        "opTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1601465922, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Did anyone encounter this before? how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your deployment is a sharded cluster, I think you have to run the command from a mongos. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/197957